# Riemann Hypothesis and Electric Dipole

Tags: physics, riemann-zeta

I recently watched 3Blue1Brown's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw) on the Riemann zeta function (excellent video by the way), and basically he shows what analytic continuation is and how it relates to the function. In order to visualize the Riemann zeta function being applied to the complex plane, he takes the horizontal and vertical lines on the regular complex plane and then draws what they look like after the Riemann zeta function has been applied. [image] I happened to notice that this image looks like the equipotential lines and field lines in an electric dipole [image].

This leads me to two questions:

1. Is the picture from 3Blue1Brown's video the same thing as equipotential lines and field lines in an electric dipole?
2. If so, why should this be true? I'm still learning calculus, so if it's too advanced don't bother explaining it, but if not's that complicated I'd love to hear why.

Comment: I do not know the deeper significance of this specific example but "complex analytic" functions are, very generally (i.e. outside of the specific context of the zeta function) associated with families of mutually orthogonal curves.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851777/prove-that-these-families-of-level-curves-are-orthogonal, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: It's true due to the properties of gradients, which you will learn if you take vector calculus in the future.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4142487/688539,  everything looks like an electric dipole